# ruby private class method helper

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Hi I am trying to create a helper for mass defining ruby methods as private class methods. In general one can define a method as a private class method by using private_class_method key work. But I would like to create a helper in the following style:

```
class Person
  define_private_class_methods do 
    def method_one
    end

    def method_two
    end
  end
end
```

The way I planned to dynamically define this is in the following way, which is not at all working:

```
class Object
  def self.define_private_class_methods &block
    instance_eval do
      private
      &block
    end
  end
end
```

any ideas where I might be going wrong?

Comment: This is confusing. I would expect that calling `#private_class_methods` on a class will give me a list of private class methods similarly to `#private_instance_methods`. But setting that aside, why do you want to do this? To better your understanding of Ruby's mechanics or to actually use it in general?

Comment: more about understanding the mechanics of how private class methods work and also to use in my code. If the naming is bad, maybe we can rename the method to define_private_class_methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could define the methods in an anonymous module by passing the block to [`Module.new`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Module.html#method-c-new), make each instance method in the module [`private`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Module.html#method-i-private) and [`extend`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Object.html#method-i-extend) your class with the module:

```
class Class
  def define_private_class_methods(&block)
    mod = Module.new(&block)
    mod.instance_methods.each { |m| mod.send(:private, m) }
    extend(mod)
  end
end
```

This has the desired result:

```
class Person
  define_private_class_methods do 
    def method_one
      123
    end
  end
end

Person.send(:method_one)
#=> 123

Person.method_one
#=> private method `method_one' called for Person:Class (NoMethodError)
```

... and as a bonus, it also gives you a `super` method: (probably of little use)

```
class Person
  def self.method_one
    super * 2
  end
end

Person.method_one
#=> 456
```

Of course, you don't have to use `extend`, you could just as well define the methods manually:

```
class Class
  def define_private_class_methods(&block)
    mod = Module.new(&block)
    mod.instance_methods.each do |m|
      define_singleton_method(m, mod.instance_method(m))
      private_class_method(m)
    end
  end
end
```

The essential component is the anonymous module, so you have a (temporary) container to define the methods in.

Comment: This is the best answer here so far. The only drawback is that blind `extend(mod)` is potentially harmful... Well, there are no drawbacks in that approach :)

Answer (score 5):

**`$ cat /tmp/a.rb`**

```
class Object
  def self.define_private_class_methods &cb
    existing = methods(false)
    instance_eval &cb
    (methods(false) - existing).each { |m| singleton_class.send :private, m }
  end
end

class Person
  define_private_class_methods do 
    def method_one
            puts "¡Yay!"
    end
  end
end

Person.send(:method_one)
Person.public_send(:method_one)
```

**`$ ruby /tmp/a.rb`**

```
¡Yay!

/tmp/a.rb:18:in `public_send': private method `method_one' 
                 called for Person:Class (NoMethodError)
Did you mean?  method
    from /tmp/a.rb:18:in `<main>'
```

Please note, that it’s hard to understand, what you are trying to achieve and possibly there is better, cleaner and more robust way to achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 5):

Similar, yet different (and semantically more correct IMHO) to @mudasobwa's answer:

```
class Class
  def define_private_class_methods(&definition)
    class_methods_prior = methods

    singleton_class.class_eval(&definition)

    (methods - class_methods_prior).each do |method_name|
      private_class_method method_name
    end
  end
end

class Person
  define_private_class_methods do 
    def method_one
      1
    end
  end
end

Person.method_one # !> NoMethodError: private method `method_one' called for Person:Class
Person.send :method_one # => 1
```

**Note**: It will not change the accessibility of a class method that you are currently overwriting.

Comment: By “semantically more correct” you mean that it produces a temporary array of hundreds of elements instead of a few? :)

Comment: @mudasobwa, I don't see the difference in array size other than that you filter already private methods. I can also do that, but it's besides the point. The point is that you want to define some magical method for classes. You should modify `Class`, not `Object`.

Comment: This won't work if you want to overwrite an existing method with a private one.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, true. I don't see a way around it other than define a `method_added` hook temporarily and then remove it. And you will also have to save the old `method_added` hook if one was present and restore it. It adds 5 times the complexity to the current implementation.

Comment: The latter might be resolved as `singleton_class.prepend(Module.new { def method_added(...); do_smth if in_block; super; end })`. BTW, I re-opened `Object` because the OP was reopening `Object`. Nothing personal to `Class` :)

Comment: @mudasobwa, that is actually an awesome solution. It should totes be the accepted answer. Please do write it down! (:

Comment: @mudasobwa, actually I don't see a way to unprepend it afterwards. And yes - it doesn't hurt, but It feels dirty to have a leftover module in the ancestors chain.

Comment: @ndn there is no way to unprepend, save for undeclare a constant and force `require` afterwards.

Comment: @mudasobwa you have to know all files with possible monkey patches and that requiring them doesn't change anything else.

Comment: @ndn monkeypatchers are none of our business!